# Access local storage in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, backgroundworker

I want to access local storage in chrome extension based on manifest version 3

I am having a local-storage item with key as name now i want to console the name every time it changes in local storage in chrome extension

earlier it was used to be like this

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function (changes, namespace) {
chrome.action.setBadgeText({text:changes.total.newValue.toString();
chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: '#9688F1'});
});
```

But not working with version 3

what can be done to do this

Comment: The code is correct, so the problem is elsewhere in your code. Use devtools to debug it or show all relevant code. A common mistake is to confuse `localStorage` with `chrome.storage.local`.